# Angular 8.1.3 Error: No value provided for @angular/core symbol 'ɵɵinjectAttribute'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on a medium-scale project using angular/ionic and as of recently I, out of nowhere, received this horrific error.  I haven't done anything different or new it just appeared one day after running `ionic serve`.

Ionic v6.13.1
Angular v8.1.3
Node.js v6.14.11

The angular ngcc seems to stop working and gives me an error in Vscode, then in the browser I receive an error saying:

```
ERROR Error: No value provided for @angular/core symbol 'ɵɵinjectAttribute'.
    at R3JitReflector.resolveExternalReference (compiler.js:6079)
    at JitEmitterVisitor.visitExternalExpr (compiler.js:6016)
    at ExternalExpr.visitExpression (compiler.js:1276)
    at JitEmitterVisitor.visitInvokeFunctionExpr (compiler.js:5524)
    at JitEmitterVisitor.visitInvokeFunctionExpr (compiler.js:5855)
    at InvokeFunctionExpr.visitExpression (compiler.js:1233)
    at compiler.js:5695
    at JitEmitterVisitor.visitAllObjects (compiler.js:5714)
    at JitEmitterVisitor.visitAllExpressions (compiler.js:5695)
    at JitEmitterVisitor.visitInstantiateExpr (compiler.js:5564)
```

I did some research and I tried:

1. Turning ivy off in my package.json:

   "enableIvy": false
2. Adding a ngcc.config.ts file and adding it to my package.json to set deepImports off (which was my previous error message)

None seems to work, I also saw that Ivy is actually introduce in angular v9+ so I'm not sure if that is even the issue here..

Any suggestions, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting the `node_modules/` folder and run `npm install` again. Could be a corrupted dependency.

Comment: I did the same and the error persist, nobody tries this?